# Samba share shows as available, but can't be accessed

Tags: linux, samba

I'm having problems getting Samba sharing working on a fairly stock version of Debian (technically Raspbian, but that's not all that different from Debian.)  The Samba logs are giving me errors like the following:

```
[2013/05/05 04:07:39.988912,  0] smbd/service.c:995(make_connection_snum)
  Can't become connected user!
```

And this is when I'm just trying to connect to it by doing `smbclient \\localhost\extrastorage` (which gives me the error `tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`.)

I know that it's available because I can run `smbclient -L localhost` and get the following:

```
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.6]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        extrastorage    Disk      Place to store stuff
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (raspberrypi server)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.6]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------
        RASPBERRYPI          raspberrypi server

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        WORKGROUP
```

So it's clearly there, and it's not a problem with the password either.

Maybe there is something wrong with my `smb.conf`, but I'm not seeing it:

```
[global]
        server string = %h server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        print ok = Yes
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[extrastorage]
        comment = Place to store stuff
        path = /mnt/extrastorage
        valid users = pi
        admin users = pi
        guest ok = Yes
```

Why am I not able to browse the shares?

Comment: We don't generally consider RP systems to be servers within the scope of our FAQ. [SU] or even [U&L] may be a better place to ask.

Comment: True, but this question seemed to be more of a Samba issue than anything else.  I just wanted to give a complete picture of my set up.

Comment: You did read the [faq] and [about] didn't you? In particular the bit about being a site for professionals ?

Comment: So, I'm not using it in that particular context here, but I could have asked the question omitting that particular detail to get to the same conclusion, right?

Comment: That's really not the pint though is it. If you choose to lie about your environment and get caught out the community will take a dim view of this. Better to ask your questions in the correct context on a site that is perfectly adequate for the non professional user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured out the problem just now.  I had to install the package `samba-common-bin` and run `smbpasswd -a pi`.

Comment: After an update I also ran into this issue - having already run `smbpasswd -a user` before it was now sufficient to run `smbpasswd -e user` to re-enable the account